# reading the Tripos mol2 file format using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to read my mol2 file which looks like:

```
@MOLECULE
19020135
 20 21 0 0 0
SMALL
GASTEIGER
@ATOM
       1 N      1.784 1.464 1.547 N.3 1  LIG1
       2 O      1.657 6.176 1.764 O.3 1  LIG1
       3 C      1.836 2.748 6.867 C.ar 1  LIG1
       4 C      1.873 3.678 3.893 C.3 1  LIG1
```

and i want output:

```
       1 N      1.784 1.464 1.547  
       2 O      1.657 6.176 1.764  
       3 C      1.836 2.748 6.867  
       4 C      1.873 3.678 3.893
```

I'm using this regular expression

```
=~/\s+\d+\s+(\w+)\s+(\S+\.\S+)\s+(\S+\.\S+)\s+(\S+\.\S+)\s+(\w{1})\s+.+\s+/ig)
```

Please kindly help me to get read my file so i get the desired output

Comment: Have you tried searching http://search.cpan.org/ for a module that can do all this complicated work for you? Perhaps [this one](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Bio%3A%3APDB%3A%3AStructure)?

Comment: Also, if you want help with your Perl code, you should probably actually show the Perl code, and not just the regex you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `@WORD` is the record separator here, you can read the records on by one by setting the input record separator `$/`. Then you can just remove the 3 last columns with a substitution and print them.

The `/m` modifier allows `$` to match newline in a multiline string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = '@';
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;       # remove @ from end
    if (s/^ATOM\n//) {
        s/(?:\s+\S+){3}$//gm;
        print;
    }
}

__DATA__
@MOLECULE
19020135
 20 21 0 0 0
SMALL
GASTEIGER
@ATOM
       1 N      1.784 1.464 1.547 N.3 1  LIG1
       2 O      1.657 6.176 1.764 O.3 1  LIG1
       3 C      1.836 2.748 6.867 C.ar 1  LIG1
       4 C      1.873 3.678 3.893 C.3 1  LIG1
```

**Output:**

```
       1 N      1.784 1.464 1.547
       2 O      1.657 6.176 1.764
       3 C      1.836 2.748 6.867
       4 C      1.873 3.678 3.893
```

**Usage:**

Change `<DATA>` to `<>` and then:

```
perl script.pl input.txt > output.txt
```

Redirecting to output file is optional.

**Update:** You can also use a ["flip-flop"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) to determine the borders of the record, which possibly is the better solution. In this case, you do not need the `/gm` modifiers.

```
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^\@ATOM$/ ... /^\@/) {    # the "flip-flop"
        next if /^\@/;
        s/(?:\s+\S+){3}$//;
        print;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is tagged `perl` but here is an `awk` solution (not retaining original whitespace). This will even work with multiple records where `@ATOM` functions as record separator since your input file format is not entirely clear:

```
$ awk '/^@ATOM/,/^@ATOM/{t=1; next} t && NF>1{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' test.txt
1 N 1.784 1.464 1.547
2 O 1.657 6.176 1.764
3 C 1.836 2.748 6.867
4 C 1.873 3.678 3.893
```

Comment: Will this work if `@ATOM` is not the last record in the file?

Comment: @TLP Can you rephrase? How is `@ATOM` the last record currently? This discards everything up to `/^@ATOM/` and then prints the first five columns for every non-empty line. Since OP hasn't specified the input format further this is what I assumed they want which, of course, could be a false assumption.

Comment: I was working under the assumption that `@WORD` is the record separator in the file format he is using. If so, it could be that there are more records, and ATOM is not the last.

Comment: Your comment actually inspired me to add the alternate solution to my answer. Is there a similar thing in awk? I seem to recall there is.

Comment: Actually it does! You can specify a range by separating patterns with a comma, e.g. `/start/,/end/{do_foo}`. I might update my answer as well :-)

Comment: There you go, now it also works under your assumption :) Just tested yours, have an upvote!

Comment: Then I can also upvote yours and thank you for the inspiration. :)

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth The range might end up printing `20 21 0 0 0` if there are more than 1 molecule (hard to say given the sample data). Here is an alternate solution if OP doesn't care of trailing newlines `awk 'BEGIN{RS="@";FS=OFS="\n"}$1=="ATOM"{$1="";print}' file`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
    if ($_ =~ /(\d+\h+[A-Z][a-z]?\d*\h+(?: -?[\d.]+){3})/) {
        print $1 . "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
@MOLECULE
19020135
 20 21 0 0 0
SMALL
GASTEIGER
@ATOM
       1 N      1.784 1.464 1.547 N.3 1  LIG1
       2 O      1.657 6.176 1.764 O.3 1  LIG1
       3 C      1.836 2.748 6.867 C.ar 1  LIG1
       4 C      1.873 3.678 3.893 C.3 1  LIG1
```